# Respond to WPF ComboBox DoubleClick of item

Tags: wpf

How can I respond to a WPF ComboBox's ComboBoxItem being double-clicked? Right now when it is double-clicked it closes the ComboBox and clicks whatever is below. I'd like to take an action with the item that was double-clicked and prevent the event from going any further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to have a control in the ComboBox's `ItemTemplate` which will occupy the entire space of the `ComboBoxItem` and will handle the `DoubleClick` event. Something like this:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    MouseDoubleClick="Button_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still interested in this, but I've spent an unfortunate amount of time researching a work-around without success. Finally, I found a solution that works reasonably well, and it's similar to Adi's comment.

1) Place a TextBox over the text box area of the ComboBox control. Don't cover the drop-down button.
2) Use the "BringToFront" operator on this TextBox through code or with the IDE.
3) Set the Data Binding "Text" property of the TextBox to the same binding source and field as your ComboBox.
4) Set the DoubleClick Event for the TextBox, to do whatever you want to do.

That's it.